# Этимология жаргонизма "туфта"

Tags: этимология

Туфта - чушь, бред, пустые слова.  Может ли это слово происходить от "тавтология",  произносимого как 
"та(ф)тология"?

Comment: В действительности это очень интересный вопрос, я чуть позже отвечу на него (нашла статью про это слово в книге о русском жаргоне).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из книги М.А. Грачев, В.М. Мокиенко "Русский жаргон" (историко-этимологический словарь).

В 20-е годы **туфта** в языке деклассированных элементов имела значение "**поддельный кусок мануфактуры**", ***туфтальщик*** ― аферист по подделке мануфактуры, ***туфтарь, туфтач*** ― мошенник, обманщик, лгун, ***тухта*** ― плохая вещь.

Этимологической основой слова ***туфта*** стала ***тафта*** ― гладкая, тонкая шелковая ткань, но не исключено влияние и других слов, например ***тафтуй,тахтуй*** ― стар. **сагайдак**.

Из словаря: САГАЙДАК 1. чехол для лука. 2. устар. набор вооружения конного лучника, лук с налучием и колчан со стрелами в общем чехле (тохтуе). 3. диал. лук).

Вариант ***тухта*** ушел из языка, а слово **туфта** получило широкое распространение (гнать туфту, покупать туфту).

В арго ГУЛАГа ***туфта*** (реже *тухта*) ― это фальшивая работа. Была даже придумана аббревиатура ― ***ТФТ*** (тяжелый физический труд). Спрашиваете с нас ТФТ? Так мы вам покажем ***тэфэту***.